# Retrieving data from blockchain with random id's

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have a blockchain where it stores business details.
Currently, I store them using ids like **BIZ1, BIZ2** but I need to store the ids like **BIZ_erte38, BIZ_231sds**.
Once it's done, is there a way to retrieve all the businesses that are currently in the network.
**BIZ_erte38 BIZ_231sds**  these id's work fine when I get the individual business details. 
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your question was really bad written.
I tried to fix it but it still unreadable, I think you should explain better the context.

Apart from this, the blockchain is by definition **immutable**, so that if you want modify it **ID1** into something like **ID_1**, you cannot do it.

What you can do is that you can totally re-write **ID1** by doing a new transaction and calling it **ID_1**, but you cannot modify what you inserted in the blocks.

Comment: I do not need to edit the existing records, i just need to save the ids using the generated string and get all the businesses in the network

Comment: If you register under the same ID, let's say ID1, all the info regarding that business, then you can call a "getHistory" from the SDK and you will get all the transactions done using the ID **ID1**